# Laravel: How to get the value from the checkbox along with the value from the text input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have input `id` and `ballance`, `id` as check box and `ballance` as text input. I want when the `id` is checked, the `ballance` request matches the `id` that was checked. but at this time all `ballance` entered into request. How to solve the problem from front-end & back-end?

My view:

[image: view]

My view code:

```
<th>
    <div>
        <input name="id[]" value="{{$item->id}}" type="checkbox"> <label class="" for="{{$item->id}}"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<td> {{ $item->id }} </td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm txtInt saldoChild" name="ballance[]" size="1" id="{{$item->id}}" value="0">
</td>
```

My return of request:

[image]

My backend:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{       
    return $request;
}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when an `input` in html is `disabled`, the value of that wont send to controller.

so try this:

```
<script>
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.saldoChild').prop("disabled",false); //Enable the textBox
        }
        else{
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.saldoChild').prop("disabled",true);  //Disable the textbox
       }
    });
</script>
```

and at the page loading you have to `Disable` All `input type text`, that the `checkbox` of this `tr` is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is that you have your balance array. so you can get those value who are not 0 and push them to new array and then you are good to go!
first index of id array is for first index of your new array. you can store them in another array or in db

Comment: if like this it will loop all existing data, in terms of the process it will take more time, before that, thank you for the response